# Facebook api version deprecation

Tags: android, facebook

I have a facebook app that uses api v2.2 and got noticed that 2.2 will be deprecated mar 27th. When I follow the link to the version upgrade tool, I get

**Your app hasn't made enough calls to the Graph API to show any info, or there are no changes for the methods you selected between v2.2 and v2.8**

My android sdk is up-to-date. Should I ignore it or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

This message means that your app is not using the deprecated code, you don't have to do nothing, all is ok.